# How can I leave the punctuation where it is while reversing a string?

Tags: java, string

I could use some help. I am trying to reverse a String while leaving the punctuation where it is at in the string. I cannot seem to get this to work. For example the string reads "I like to write songs in my spare time." would need to return "time spare my in songs write to like I." Am I missing something here?

public class ReverseString {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String s[] = "I like to write songs in my spare time.".split(" ");
    String answer = "";

    for (int i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        answer += s[i] + " ";
    }

    System.out.println("Reversed String:");
    System.out.println(answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 1));
}
```

}

Comment: Can you give us an example input/output *with* punctuation? "I like to write songs in my spare time" has no punctuation.

Comment: . is punctuation.

Comment: Your question could have been much clearer. For example, what do you expect if the input string composes of multiple punctuations? Do you want `I ate dinner. Then I slept.` to be made `dinner ate I. slept I Then.`, or do you want `slept I Then. dinner ate I.`? Also what qualifies as a punctuation? Do different punctuation need to be handled differently? The implementation would be very different in each of those scenarios.

Comment: For better clarity this would be what I am looking for “Wherever you go, you can always find beauty.” would return as “Beauty find always, can you go you wherever.” with the comma and period staying where they are but the capitalization and the words have changed. The Wherever becomes Beauty instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
You answer.replace(".", "") use this to replace . with ""



public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            String s[] = "I like to write songs in my spare time.".split(" ");
            String answer = "";

            for (int i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                answer += s[i] + " ";
            }
            answer = answer.replace(".", "");
            System.out.println("Reversed String:");
            System.out.println(answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 1));
        }
```